# How to change font color of multiInput() from shinyWidgets package

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I have below app using `shinyWidgets` package

```
library(shinyWidgets); library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  multiInput(
    inputId = "id", label = "Fruits :",
     choices = c("Banana", "Blueberry", "Cherry",
                "Coconut", "Grapefruit", "Kiwi",
                "Lemon", "Lime", "Mango", "Orange",
                "Papaya"),
    selected = "Banana", width = "400px",
     options = list(
       enable_search = FALSE,
       non_selected_header = "Choose between:",
      selected_header = "You have selected:"
    )
   ),
   verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
 )

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$res <- renderPrint({
     input$id
  })
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is it possible to customize this further. Particularly I want to change the font color to *Black* for all choices. I added below line, however it failed to change the font color

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('#id {color:#000 !important;}'))),
```

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
css <- "#id+div div a {color: black;}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(css)),
  ......
```